# javascript setHours date set to previous date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to set time to 0 using javascript's setHours() method but it changes the day of the month to one less than the actual day. Sample code:

```
var d = new Date();  //2017-09-18T04:58:34.223Z
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);  //2017-09-17T18:30:00.000Z
```

Comment: When I executed the above code in browser console it gives me this result Mon Sep 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time).

Comment: This is to be expected since the date depends on your local time. That format is in UTC and that is the current utc time base on your local time.

Comment: I am using this in node server side and giving me the exact same result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The setHours() method sets the hours for a specified date according to local time, and returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC until the time represented by the updated Date instance.

To set the time to midnight in universal time ,use `setUTCHours()`.

> The getUTCHours() method returns the hours in the specified date according to universal time.

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toISOString());
date.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

Answer (score 1):

`d.toLocaleString()` gives you the local date-time

```js
var d = new Date();  
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);  

console.log('date', d)

console.log('local date', d.toLocaleString())

console.log(d.toGMTString())

console.log(d.toISOString())
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in your code. What you are checking is the JSON format of the date.

```
var d = new Date();
d.toString();
 //"Mon Sep 18 2017 10:47:15 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
d.toJSON();
//"2017-09-18T05:17:15.839Z"

d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
d.toString();
//"Mon Sep 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
d.toJSON();
//"2017-09-17T18:30:00.000Z"
```

If you use the getDate method, you will get 18 before and after setting hours.
So there is nothing wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think there is a problem, as you can see at my code below. Maybe you did something wrong in the middle of it.

Or you are confused with the UTC format, then try reading this https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log('d:', d)
var setToZeroTime = new Date(d.setHours(0,0,0,0))
console.log('new date: ',setToZeroTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix the issue using moment.

> moment().startOf('day');

Comment: how you did that?